# How to POST (Jersey) list of Pojos as output stream while getting Jersey RESTful client connection only once

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

This is my OrderDTO pojo class

```
public class OrderDTO implements Serializable {




 private static final long serialVersionUID = -4500200949047532187L;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("tin")
    private String tin;


    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private TicketStatus status;

    @JsonProperty("customerInfo")
    private CustomerDTO customerDTO;



    @JsonProperty("oldTicketIdReference")
    private String oldTicketIdReference;

    @JsonProperty("newTicketIdReference")
    private String newTicketIdReference;

    @JsonProperty("cancellationTermsInfo")
    private CancellationTermsDTO cancellationTermsDTO;

    @JsonProperty("cartId")
    private Long cartId;

    @JsonProperty("transactionNumber")
    private Long transactionNumber;


    @JsonProperty("umsUserId")
    private Integer umsUserId;

}
```

If I have a list of orderDTO like below and I want to get client connection once and then I just want to stream the list of orderDTO , how can I do that ? Can you please tell .
Currently my code is like this

```
final Client client = new Client();

List<OrderDTO> listOrderDto = getListOfOrders(cartId);

listOrderDto.parallelStream().forEach(orderDto->{

 client.target(
"http://localhost:8080/orders/writeAndIncrementOrder").
            header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            request.post(Entity.json(orderDto));

});
```

But I dont want to rest call multiple times , I just want to get client connection once and then posting the listOrderDto as a output stream to the client .

Comment: This is something that would also need to be supported on the server.  Does the server support accepting a JSON array?

Comment: server supports java.io.OutputStream hence i want to get the client connection once in JAX-RX POST call  and then want to send the listOrderDTO  via streaming using output stream

Comment: Ok, what problem are you actually having sending the list. Have you tried it? What happens when you do?

Comment: ya actully list is too big m size may very from 50k to 1 million , but later i have tried streaming like this , but it says                                                                                StreamingOutput outputStream = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
                    WebApplicationException {
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                listItem.parallelStream().forEach(item->{
                    try {

Comment: String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(item);
                        writer.write(str);
                        //writer.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                });
                // <-- This is very important.  Do not forget.
            }
        };
        client.target("http://localhost:8080/streamrepo/stream/check").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE).post(Entity.entity(outputStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE));

Comment: but this code says :                     2018-07-21 13:47:37.916  INFO 30986 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 1 * Client response received on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
1 < 406
1 < Content-Length: 0
1 < Date: Sat, 21 Jul 2018 08:17:37 GMT

Comment: Does the server allow you to send a list? Or can you change it to support that? It will be difficult to find a solution without either of those.